# Julia: how to prepare and cleanup @testset

Tags: testing, julia

I wonder what Julia best practices are to prepare and cleanup tests? Other programming languages have `before` and `after`, or similar named functions. Julia seems to be missing them.

Answer (score 7):

You just write the lines in the `testset`. Those having `@test` in front of them are the tests and the other lines are the setup. As easy as that.

```
julia> using Test

julia> @testset "my big set" begin
       x=4
       y=2
       @test 2y == x
       end
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
my big set    |    1      1
Test.DefaultTestSet("my big set", Any[], 1, false)
```

Similarly after `@test` lines you can de-allocate resources etc.

Comment: While @testset will prevent variables from leaking from one test to another, `using` s from one testset can still influence another, so to be absolutely sure that one @testset doesn't interfere with another current best practices appears to be instead using @safetestset from https://github.com/YingboMa/SafeTestsets.jl, which puts each testset in an entirely separate module.

Comment: It is very interesting tool indeed. However, I am wondering in what scenarios I want to have such strict separation. For sure the user of my library will load a full battery of packages to do their job. Hence a scenario where only a small subset of packages is loaded is kind of unrealistic in practice. Last but not least packages having such broad side effects is not something I would like to meet :) One scenario I can imagine testing with different subsets of packages loaded could be a plotting library that tries to discover loaded back-ends and behave accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do setup just as Przemysław proposed. However, in order to ensure proper cleanup you need to handle it manually. The reason is that if an uncaught exception is thrown within `@testset` but outside `@test` it will lead to termination immediately:

```
julia> @testset begin
       throw(ArgumentError("something went wrong"))
       @test true
       @test false
       end
test set: Error During Test at REPL[5]:1
  Got exception outside of a @test
  ArgumentError: something went wrong
...

Test Summary: | Error  Total
test set      |     1      1
ERROR: Some tests did not pass: 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 errored, 0 broken.
```

Therefore if you have some code that might throw an exception you have to handle it manually, e.g.:

```
julia> @testset begin
       try
           @test true
           throw(ArgumentError("some error"))
           @test false
       catch
           @info "caught"
       finally
           @info "cleanup"
       end
       end
[ Info: caught
[ Info: cleanup
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
test set      |    1      1
Test.DefaultTestSet("test set", Any[], 1, false)
```

(note that the second test was not run, as earlier an exception outside of `@test` was thrown)